# How to find all the terms of a polynomial that contain a specific variable in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, polynomials, polynomial-math

Let say that we have the polynomial `f=a^2*b+b^2*c+c*d`.

I would like to know if, in Matlab, I could find all the terms of `f` that
contain specific polynomials of variables `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

For example, if I have a polynomial of variable `c`, that is `g=b`,
then I want to find out the terms: `a^2+b*c`.

If I have a polynomial of variable `b`, that is `g=c`,
then I want to find out the terms: `b^2+d`.

It is like to take a common factor (polynomial of a variable) and then to find the terms that contains this factor.

I know that I can use `factor()`, but I have polynomials in which the usage of `factor()` does not work, because they cannot be written as a product of polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusingly worded. As far as I can tell, you have a polynomial in several variables, and want to reduce the power on all of a given variable by 1, and remove the terms which are constant with respect to that variable. Here is a way to do that:

```
syms a b c d
f=a^2*b+b^2*c+c*d

[p,q] = coeffs(f,c)
% p = [ b^2 + d, a^2*b]
% q = [ c, 1]

sum(p(1:end-1).*q(2:end))
```

`coeffs` returns the coefficients of the various powers of `c` in the expression `f`, returning the coefficients in `p` and the powers of `c` in `q`. Then multiply the `i`-th entry of `p` by the `I+1`-th entry of `q` and add them up.